# Jobeet for Symfony 2 error

Tags: php, symfony, jobeet

I try to set up jobeet using git and when i try to open `localhost/jobeet/web` I get `class not found`:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Erlem\JobeetBundle\Repository\JobRepository' not found in
 D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\joobet\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory.php on line 75
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you tell us a little more about the problem and what question you have?

Comment: Hi, I've reformatted your question slightly and added tags. See '[editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)' for more information on this. It will help if you give an example of the code you are running and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you say git, you didn't include the code with the composer right?
Have a look at

1. https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md how to include git repositories and then
2. add it to your autoloader https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading